# Removing duplicate records from a joined table and leaving the last occurrence records?

Tags: sql-server

I am having two tables one Table A having some records. Table B having some modified date,inserted date of the Table A. Now i have to join two table and get top 3 records without duplicates.

```
**Table A** 
id  name 
1   Arul
2   siva
3   raja
4   sanju

**Table B**
Id modifed TabId(Refered Table A) Modified Date
1  inserted    1                  2014-08-08 10:46:42.250
2  updated     1                  2014-08-08 10:46:42.624
3  inserted    2                  2014-08-08 10:46:42.724
4  inserted    3                  2014-08-08 10:46:43.624
5  inserted    4                  2014-08-08 10:46:44.624
6  updated     4                  2014-08-08 10:47:42.624
7  updated     4                  2014-08-08 10:48:42.624
8  updated     3                  2014-08-08 10:49:42.624
```

Comment: Please provide some information! What is the table structure, the values.....

Comment: Provide table structure

Comment: okay wait sir i will give...

Comment: Do you want to get all records form tablea and tableb ah?

Comment: no i want to get only 3 records with out duplications

Comment: do you want to get id and name only ah?

Comment: yeah i want to get name only in descending order by using Modified Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT a.Id, a.Name,b.ModifiedDate,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Id ORDER BY b.ModifiedDate) AS RowNumber
         from tableA a, tableB b where a.id  = b.TabId ) AS temp
WHERE   temp.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: i need Table A id,name and Table B Modifieddate and the Table A id not duplicates

Comment: Its giving result but the Table A id will give duplicate.The table A id records will give some duplicates

Comment: @user3326931  can you please check above query after removing "top 3" and tell me ... duplication is gone or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 Select distinct top 3 a.*,Modified Date from tablea a 
inner join tableb b on (a.Id=b.TabId) 
order by Modified Datedesc;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/342ce5/1)

Comment: I think Distinct TOP N is right syntax instead of TOP N Distinct. @user3326931 try my answer !

Comment: Its Showing Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.